# vb..NET Pause/Resume a file copy (like windows 8 button)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, file-io, visual-studio-2012

Can we PAUSE and RESUME a file copy ?

- Using :

3 `Button`_
1 `OpenFileDialog`_
1 `FolderBrowserDialog`

- Imports :

  `Imports System.IO`
- Code :

  ```
  Private Sub BTN_filedialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_filedialog.Click

  OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" 'Cette clé de registre ouvre "Ordinateur"
  OpenFileDialog1.Title =
  OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
  OpenFileDialog1.Filter = _
  "All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"

  Dim dlgResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

  If dlgResult <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      MessageBox.Show("File Error " & dlgResult)
  End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub BTN_folderbrowserdialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_folderbrowserdialog.Click

  Dim dlgResult = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
  If dlgResult <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      MessageBox.Show("Folder Error " & dlgResult)
  End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub BTN_copyfile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_copyfile.Click

  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( _
  OpenFileDialog1.FileName, _
  FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\" & _
  OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName, _
  FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
  End Sub
  ```

I use `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile`

With Windows 8, inside the dialog box "copy", there is a pause button.

How to call this "event" ?

I do not know if this is possible, but can we send parameters to a certain Lib /. Dll to **simulate the action of pressing the pause button** ?

Ps : Sorry for my bad english, i'm french.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this would be to ignore the FileSystem.CopyFile command completely. Instead, use a FileStream to open the file you wish to copy, read the bytes, create a new file to the target destination, and write the bytes to that location.

You can read and write the file in smaller chunks so that you can check to see if a pause variable is set to true. For example, if you create a pause button, set a global variable "bCopyPaused = true". In the custom copy function you can use a simple if statement and check if bCopyPaused == true and pause the operation. You'll need to keep track of the last copied or written bytes to allow the operation to be resumed.

Here's some examples of using FileStream: http://vb.net-informations.com/files/vb.net_FileStream.htm